# Error in source code of SlidingDrawer in Android

Tags: android

From the source of SlidingDrawer, I found an interesting thing.
http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java.shtml

In line around 445, you may see there is a variable `mBottom`.
However, I haven't see where is the declaration and initialisation.
So the question is why it can be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mBottom` is a protected field of `View`, since `SlidingDrawer` is child of `View` it has access to protected fields. so that's why it can be compiled

Comment: Now I copy and paste the source code to my Project. And it highlighted an error, how can I fix it.

Comment: use getter method `getBottom()` will return value of `mBottom` field